# How to write document download event to the external system?

Tags: events, sharepoint-2010, download, document-library

I need to write event to the external system when document in library is downloaded by user.

There is no download event in list.
Should I retrieve this information from audit reports? If yes, how to do it - there is no 'audit web service' in SP.

Maybe is any easier way to do it?

Thanks in advance, Chris.

~ I finally use http module: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/14447/logging-document-library-downloads-with-httpmodule

Answer (score 0):

This type of event is not available via the EventHandler framework. There is no download specific event, but there is a view event available from the AuditEntry object.  However, there is no way to differentiate between the user clicking the link to view the document and downloading it.

One option I would look at is create a custom action for the document library.  This custom action would download the document and write the information required for the external system.  To make it completely effective, you will need to disable the ability to right-click and download the link so the user is forced to go through your custom action.